# Typescript defining a state passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, next.js

```
export interface ISideBarProps {
  open: any
  setOpen: any
}

export default function SideBar({ open, setOpen }: ISideBarProps) {
  return (
    <div
      className={`absolute left-0 top-0 h-screen w-[40vw] bg-gray-100 ${open ? "block" : "hidden"}`}
    >
      Sidebar
    </div>
  )
}
```

How would i define open and setopen properly as boolean states

Comment: Use ```open: boolean```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
export interface ISideBarProps {
open:boolean,
setOpen:(open:boolean)=>void
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vida Hedayati's comment in this thread is by far the most correct answer.

`setOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>`

Answer (score -1):

Change the type of `open` and `setOpen` to `boolean` instead of `any` as below.

```
export interface ISideBarProps {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: boolean;
}
```

Comment: ```open:boolean,setOpen:React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>```